# Scrapy, can you limit crawl time on domain level?

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

I'm having issues with my spider getting stuck in forums where it can stay crawling for days without finding much at all. Is there anyway to limit crawling a certain site (based on start_url) to a certain amount of time? Any other solution to this issue?

Comment: Would really appriciate any help with this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was to use [process_links](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html?highlight=process_links#crawlspider) and create a method that checks the time:

```
 rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=()), callback='parse_obj', follow=True, process_links='check_for_semi_dupe'),)


#Method to try avoiding spider traps and endless loops
def check_for_semi_dupe(self, links):
  for link in links:
    domainparts = urlparse(link.url)
    just_domain = domainparts[1].replace("www.", "")
    url_indexed = 0
    if just_domain not in self.processed_dupes:
      self.processed_dupes[just_domain] = datetime.datetime.now()
    else:
      url_indexed = 1
      timediff_in_sec = int((datetime.datetime.now() - self.processed_dupes[just_domain]).total_seconds())
    if just_domain in self.blocked:
      print "*** Domain '%s' was blocked! ***" % just_domain
      print "*** Link was: %s" % link.url
      continue
    elif url_indexed == 1 and timediff_in_sec > (self.time_threshhold * 60):
      self.blocked.append(just_domain)
      continue
    else:
      yield link
```

The method registers the datetime of the first time a domain appears for crawling. A class variable, "time_threshold", is defined with the desired crawl time in minutes. When the spider is fed with links to crawl the method determines wether the link should be passed along for crawling or blocked.